# Project Euler #3 In C++

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge

The question for reference:

> **The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?**
>   *answer: 6857*

I'm looking for general feedback as to style and particularly usage of the STL.  Efficiency is a concern but a simple link to a better algorithm will suffice.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
std::list<T> TrialFactorization(T n) {
    std::list<T> base_factors;
    if(n == 1 || n == 2)
        base_factors.push_back(n);
    for(T p = 2; p < n; ++p) {
        while(n % p == 0) {
            n /= p;    // <~~ Shortens outer for-loop.
            base_factors.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    if(n != 1)
        base_factors.push_back(n);
    return base_factors;
}

int main() {
    typedef long long my_type;
    my_type my_int = 600851475143LL;
    std::list<my_type> my_base_factors = TrialFactorization<my_type>(my_int);
    // std::cout << *std::max_element(my_base_factors.begin(), my_base_factors.end());
    // Exploit sorted.
    std::cout << (* --my_base_factors.end());
}
```

Comment: could have used `my_base_factors.back()` instead of `*(--my_base_factors.end())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve the performance of the inner divisibility test by using [`std::div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) to do the division and modulo operations in one step. The following should work:

```
    for (;;) {
        auto r = std::div(n, p);
        if (r.rem != 0) {
            break;
        }
        n = r.quot;
        base_factors.push_back(p);
    }
```

The return value of `std::div` is a type such as `std::lldiv_t` (the exact return type ultimately depends on the template type parameter `T`).

Comment: For templates, `auto` is the way to go to get the actual return type of `std::div` whatever the integer type.

Comment: @Morwenn: Of course, thanks. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**An optimisation**

You are getting the prime factorisation testing divisibility of various numbers.

You know that if you find a divisors `p` that way, it has to be prime but it will also be such that `p * p <= n` (`n` being the "current" version of the variable, not the one passed as an argument). Thus, you can stop the loop much earlier : `for(T p = 2; p*p <= n; ++p)`.

**A tiny bug**

Because this has no impact on your code, you have no particular way to identify this but the prime decomposition of 2 gives 2*2 which is obviously wrong.

It could be interesting to add (in the debug version) some check that the product of the factors gives the original number.

Answer (score 0):

Overall looks good.

You may speed `TrialFactorization` up about twice (doesn't touch asymptotics though) by special casing `p == 2`. Then in the loop you can increment `p` by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Like this `while(p == 2 || n % p == 0)`?

Comment: @cheezsteak: `while (n % 2 == 0) { n /= 2; }` followed by `for (p = 3; p < n; p += 2) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the type outright, you can just let the compiler do the work for you.

```
int main() {
    auto my_int = 600851475143LL;
    auto my_base_factors = TrialFactorization(my_int);
    std::cout << (* --my_base_factors.end()); 
}
```